# How do I pick a suitable SMD mosfet to control a 24V pneumatic valve with PIC32?

Tags: mosfet, pic, surface-mount, solenoid-valve

I need to control a valve (https://datasheet.octopart.com/VXZ242FGA-SMC-datasheet-110849414.pdf) of which I do not know its power consumption and drawn current. I don't have the part yet and usually it is controlled by a PLC, but for my application, I need to control it myself using a PIC32 microcontroller. It operates on 24 Volts and the entire PCB is made with SMD components, so I prefer to use one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the power required you missed it.

[image]

*Solenoid coil specifications from page 2 of the datasheet. (Click for high-resolution.)*

The worst case is 15 W on the DC versions so allow for \$ I = \frac P V = \frac {24}{15} \ \text A \$.

Go for a MOSFET that is rated at > 1 A and can be turned fully on by a logic-level output from your PIC32 - 3.3 V or 5 V, as required.

Comment: If you're choosing a little 1A one, check the power dissipation in the FET itself using the ON resistance at your choice of drive voltage. Then compute its temperature rise from its thermal resistance. You may find a 3A or 5A one has a lower ON resistance and a bigger package (lowet thermal resistance).